# chef の knife node create をエディターへの入力なしで実行したい

Tags: chef

chef infra serverに対してworkstationからknifeコマンドでnodeを作成したいのですが，

```
knife node create [node_name]
```

とするとその後エディターでnodeの情報の入力が求められると思います．
この部分を自動化したいのですがcliのみでnodeの作成をする方法はあるのでしょうか．

Answer (score 0):

ドキュメントを見る限り、予め用意した JSON ファイルを指定してノードを作成する方法があるようです。

https://docs.chef.io/workstation/knife_node/#from-file

> Use the `from file` argument to create a node using existing node data as a template.
>
> **Example: Create a node using a JSON file**
>
> ```sh
> knife node from file "PATH_TO_JSON_FILE"
> ```

Comment: ありがとうございます！`from file`コマンドを見落としていたみたいです．

https://github.com/normanjoyner/chef-api    


↑素直にchefserverのapiを叩きに行くことで解決しました！